# PHP - Only variables can be passed by reference

Tags: php, sockets, variables, tcp

```
$v1['ip'] = $url;
```

.

why isn´t the following working ?

```
$sock = @stream_socket_client('tcp://'.$v1['ip'].':25565'. $errno, $errstr, 1);
```

but this:

```
$sock = @stream_socket_client('tcp://'.$v1['ip'].':25565'. $errno, $errstr);
```

and this:

```
$sock = @stream_socket_client('tcp://'.$url.':'.$port, $errno, $errstr, 1);
```

what is the default timeout ?

Comment: Please don’t suppress errors! It just makes things unnecessarily hard.

Comment: with the `@` symbols what you are using. just remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first example, you're concatenating the remote socket with the error number, so `$errstr` is actually the error number, and `1` is the error string. PHP can't assign to `1`, so the call fails.

To find the default timeout, have a look at the docs for [`stream_socket_client()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php). In the function signature, you can see the `$timeout` parameter defaults to the float returned by `ini_get("default_socket_timeout")`, so all you have to do is echo that or look in your PHP config, and you have the default timeout.

Comment: What do you mean by *get*? Your call should look like this: `stream_socket_client('tcp://' . $v1['ip'] . ':25565', $errno, $errstr);`.